# Why aren't my projectiles drawn on the screen?

Tags: c#, xna, 2d

So I am developing a simple C# program that allows you to move around a graphic and have it fire bullets that travel from the player to the position of the mouse at the time of the mouse click. I'm still new to C# but have some experience with Java and Python.

I am fully able to move my character with the WASD but unable to get the bullets to be drawn let alone get them to move as they update.

Where might the bug be?

The projectile object's draw method?
The Game1 class's update method for the user input?
The projectile's object's direction setting?

Here is the full code:
http://pastebin.com/j5QVLKU3

I left the player class out, but it has nothing more then a few player variables like health.

Comment: Where's the constructor for the Projectile class?

Answer (score 6):

For start, could you move

```
mouseStateCurrent = Mouse.GetState();

if (mouseStateCurrent.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    if (mouseStatePrevious.LeftButton != ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        AddProjectile(player.positionPlayer);

        mouseStatePrevious = mouseStateCurrent; //<-- This line
    }
}
//<-- Here
```

Once you press your button, you're never gonna enter that if again.

### Edit 1

Furthermore, this in your Projectile

```
    Player playerObject = new Player();
    Game1 gameObject = new Game1();
```

has to look like:

```
    Player playerObject;
    Game1 gameObject;

    public Projectile(Player player, Game1 game)
    {
        playerObject = player;
        gameObject = game;
    }
```

Since you're using those only to get the origin and destination for the bullet, it would be better if you just calculated those outside, and passed them with the initialize. (because it would remove Projectile's need to know what Game1 and Player objects looked like)

You could also completely remove the Initialize method and just use Projectile's constructor, that seems more natural. (if you use the constructor for this, then you know that any time you have an instance, you can use it without having to call additional methods)

#### Slight edit

I don't think you really need the bulletOrigin in your Projectile class, you could just use the position, and move it from there to the bulletDestination.

Also, Vector2 class is made with operator overloaded methods, so you could use

```
positionBullet += directionLine*velocity;
```

instead of

```
positionBullet = Vector2.Add(positionBullet, directionLine * velocity);
```

Other than those, your code seems fine! Tell me if it still doesn't work after these changes. Also, use your debugger to step into it, see if you can find anything interesting. :)

Comment: I took your advice and revised a bit. It is still as sloppy as ever.
The character fires the bullets however they all go towards (0,0)

My guess is that its a prob with my bullet destination...

The code:
http://pastebin.com/hBEQV4Ri

Comment: oh, a common mistake now, you need to remove Vector2 before bulletDest in your if where you check for the click :) you have declared it as a global, but here you declare it again, and then pass the global bulletDest (which is 0,0) to your Projectile constructor. This is hard to see when you've been looking at your code for too long, I know I had bugs like this often and just couldn't see.

Comment: Everything is working correctly now, thank you for all of your help.

Comment: No problem, would you mind marking this as the answer? Thanks, and have fun with XNA :)